# jquery combining multiple arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm currently doing the following to combine a number of Jquery Arrays and put the data back into the DOM - this works fine:

```
conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsArrayTemp = $.merge(conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsPinnedArray,conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsNewReplyArray);
conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsArrayTemp2 = $.merge(conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsArrayTemp,conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsOldReplyArray);
conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsArrayFinal = $.merge(conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsArrayTemp2,conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsNeverReplyArray);
$('#conversationsInBoxMessagesWrapperDIV').html(conversationsInBoxMemberUserIDsArrayFinal);
```

I wanted to ask if there is a cleaner way to do the combining? Seems overkill to have 2 Temp Arrays like this and 3 lines of code to combine 4 arrays.

thx

Comment: you have to start using shorter variable names...

Comment: ^^^ What he said, the variable names is the real overkill here.

Comment: You know you can just do `var new_arr = arr1.concat(arr2, arr3, arr4);` to join multiple arrays in plain javascript ?

Comment: And if that's not enough, you can do `$('#my_new_short_selector').empty().append(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4);`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rkt7Y/

Comment: var new_arr = arr1.concat(arr2, arr3, arr4); - great that you for this... on the long names - I hear you but I find it easier on large projects... Understand it might not be the norm... thankyou

Comment: @Adam, I disagree. Long variables names have nothing to do with understandability. Nonetheless, it hurts readability way more.